# ARM - how can I pass an argument to CustomScript extension?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I have an OUTPUTS section in my template:

```
  "outputs": {
    "MasterFirstIPConfig": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[reference(variables('masterVM'),'2016-09-01').ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateIPAddress]"
    }
  }
```

And it works as expected - I see VM's Private IP.

Next - I'd like to use this IP as an argument to `CustomScript` extension, which looks like:

```
              "settings": {
                "fileUris": [
                  "https://utils.blob.core.windows.net/scripts/swarm_master_provision.sh"
                ],
                "commandToExecute": "[concat('bash swarm_master_provision.sh ', reference(variables('masterVM'),'2016-09-01').ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateIPAddress)]"

              },
```

The problem here is that `reference()` lead to dependency error:

> error:   InvalidTemplate : Deployment template validation failed:
>   'Circular dependency detected on resource:
>   '/subscriptions/0a4f2b9c-***-40b17ef8c3ab/resourceGroups/jm-web-test-var-1/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/jm-web-test-var-1-master-vmss'.
>   Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template/#resources for usage details.'.

So question is - how can I pass private IP to the script?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Hi again :-) Thanks for comment - added link to the template.

Comment: @4c74356b41 No problem) Just let me please know when I can remove the template from Github (even without sensitive information - it's still a customer's code).

Comment: so do you want to pass the same parameter to both extensions or how you want to do that?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Yes, exactly. The plan is - run `joint` for workers and additional managers via script. But to do it - need to obtain any manager's IP, wich was deployed to master's VMSS and pass it as an argument to the `CustomScript`.

Answer (score 0):

So as you are making the IP static but letting it be assigned by the VM deployment, you are unable to reference that IP within the same resource. Makes sense.

One way of doing this would be to seperate the NIC from the VM. Instead of having it as a child resource of the VM, make it its own resource, then have the VM depend on the NIC. Then you can assign a static IP to the NIC, then reference the NIC in the network profile section of the VM, and the IP of the nic in the custom script extension.

Edit: Ah this might only work with VMs not scale sets...

Edit2: Also, the reference function is only for use in the output section of the template. After a bit more research, it looks like you can assign the IP address to the load balancer. That might work for you!

Comment: Thanks, just - I need Private IP for box from VMSS, not its external one (it's dedicated resource).

Comment: So you should know from the subnet range that you set, what the scale set IPs will be. If you set the subnet range as 10.0.0.0/24 for eg. then your nodes will always start at 10.0.0.4 then increment by 1, (The first and last address, plus 3 more addresses, are reserved by azure.) Thats not ideal rly. sorry..

Comment: Yeah, it was an idea - to use hardcoded IP, noticed that it always start with `10.0.0.4`. But it definitely doesn't look like production-solution :-) Anyway - thanks.

Comment: By the way. No - it will not always start with `0.4`. Sometimes - it could be `0.5`. So - to have an array with both `0.4` and `0.5` and try `ssh` first available? Errr...

Comment: I don't know what the rest of the template looks like - but I think Ed hit it on 2 pieces: 1) make it a static IP and 2) make it the IP of the LB.  #1 is probably optional, you *can* use reference in the properties section of a resource (in addition to outputs) but since this is a VMSS you don't always know the number if VMs you need to configure.  That sounds right off the top, but again hard to say w/o seeing the entire template - but your syntax will work just fine if dependencies are met.

Comment: `the reference function is only for use in the output section of the template.` - who told you that nonsense? @EdwardRixon

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I'm up to something here, I propose you work around that with a nested template approach.

I won't paste the whole template, but just remove the extension configuration from master VMSS, and move it to a separate template, and in your template create a new step like this:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2015-01-01",
    "name": "VMSSextension",
    "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/', variables('masterVMSSname'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
            "uri": "http://pastebin.com/raw/GsNTiAMc", ## << You can take a look at the nested template
            "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parameters": {
            "value": {
                "value": "[variables('masterVMSSname')]"
            },
            "value2": {
                "value": "[reference(variables('masterVM'),'2016-09-01').ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateIPAddress]"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only real downside - you have to upgrade the scale set members that are initially provisioned to the latest version. all the new ones would be latest (so with custom script extension). And for your "slave" VMSS, you shouldn't need nested template approach, just make it "dependOn" the "master" VMSS.

edit: Sorry it took me so long, kinda short on time nowadays.

Comment: > Sorry it took me so long
No problem, thanks anyway - really appreciated!
I'll try it tomorrow or on Monday. Or Tuesday... Preparing project to release - lot of work. And lot of issues with Azure :-(

Comment: I think so)) Bit I'm really surprised such a simple task require such complexity :-| Azure's support still can't even get what I want to achieve...

Comment: azure support is obnoxious, just use SO :)

Comment: Oh, so true! :-D

Comment: Hi, @4c74356b41. Tried it today evening - but no luck yet. `VMSSextension` deployment went with Success, but - I can't even see `/var/lib/waagent/custom-script/download/0` directory on VM in masters VMSS after deploy. 
I'll try again tomorrow, maybe missed something. If any - can I please share my test templates with you?

Comment: read my answer carefully, you need to update the working vms, to the latest image version

Comment: Sorry, not sure got it... I run new provisioning, so all VMs there is new. Also - all uses same `latest` 16.04.0-LTS Ubuntu.
What I'm concerning in is - in the Portal, in VMSS => Instances - I see _LATEST MODEL == No_. Not sure what this mean.

Comment: that means you need to upgrade it (there's a button in the portal to upgrade) and it would get redeployed and the extension would get installed.

Comment: @setevoy any luck?

Comment: Nah. Thanks for your suggestion - really appreciated, but just had no time - The Deadline on its way (3-d Apr). The "solution" was to hardcode `10.0.0.4` into the template :-| 
At least - now everything works.